# How to keep my log files in monthwise folder using java log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to keep all my log4j log files in a separate month wise folder.for Instance consider this January month logs should be kept inside January folder,once February starts it should be created inside that February month folder and vice versa.

Can anyone help me to achieve this.?

Thanks in Advance.

Below is mylog 4j config:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d
       {yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
Log to file FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'dd/MM/yyyy
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
```

below are my java codes:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CarParser1.class);

public class CarParser1 {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CarParser1.class);
static validatexml vxx=new validatexml();
static mailer mailobj=new mailer();
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 Date date=new Date();


public String getHeader()
{
         logger.info("************************************
************************************
****************************************");
    logger.info("                                         
 CAR    VALIDATOR 
V1.1                                                       ");

    logger.info("       
                      By Software Team,    Thomson Digital,   
  India. 
                                                                  ");
       logger.info("***************************
********************************
*****************************************************");
     logger.info("\n\n");
    logger.info("\nExecution Date & Time :"+dateFormat.format(date));
        logger.info("********************************
*******************************************");  
return "";
}
```

### -----------

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j only supports daily rolling logging with "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender". You can use compromised methods such as the shell script or create a customized appender.

Comment: Thank you.can you please explain it deeply? because i am not able to understand as i am new to this logging.

Comment: You can use the shell script @Jovin Thariyath introduced or extend the `DailyRollingFileAppender` log4j provided.

Comment: Hey buddy, I've implemented one and post [a gist](https://gist.github.com/holymonk/cc59fde4846666479199) on github. May this help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a linux machine you could use a shell script like this

```
MONTH=`date +%m`
YEAR=`date +%Y`
# Backup directory for logs
BKDIR="/logbackups/$YEAR/$MONTH"

#create directory
if [ ! -d "$BKDIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p $BKDIR
fi

find /path/to/logs/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /logbackups/$YEAR /$MONTH/ \;
```

and write a cron job that will run once 
in a month

```
0 0 1 * * /path/to/script
```

Comment: Thank you.Am working on windows.can u please guide to get this finished?

Comment: use robocopy for moving files older than x days, this might be helpful http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx

Comment: No mention mate, happy that it helped you :)